# UIWebView UIViewController does not load URL

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiwebview

I am currently having this issue with IOS app.

When I click on a URL button the UIWebView loads the correct URL in first instance however when I visit another page within same Web View Frame it stores that page to  its memory. When I navigate to another button and click back to previous button it shows the page that I was previously in instead of loading the URL.

What I want to achieve is when user clicks on button the UIWebView loads the URL .

My current code:

```
import UIKit

class MenuViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var oyebWebView: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        oyebWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: MenuUrl)!))


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Comment: I did its pretty much same code. It loads the page in first instance however when i browse within same WebView it does not refresh the page. it keeps the last entred page in its memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code it will work.

```
import UIKit

class MenuViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var oyebWebView: UIWebView!
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let webUrl : NSURL = NSURL(string: MenuUrl)!
        let webRequest : NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: webUrl)

        oyebWebView.loadRequest(webRequest);
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       // super.viewDidLoad()
        //super.viewWillAppear(YES)
      //  self.viewDidAppear(true)

        let webUrl : NSURL = NSURL(string: MenuUrl)!
        let webRequest : NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: webUrl)

        oyebWebView.loadRequest(webRequest);

        //oyebWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: MenuUrl)!))


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```